# How to get belongsTo target of a model, which is a through model used by two other models?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, orm, sequelize.js

Say I have model A belongsToMany to model B through model C, model C belongsTo model D. If I have an id of A, what is the best way to get terms of model D related to model A including A and B?

I think this is a common context for E-R design of database. D is an Entity, which is related to the Relation C of Entity A and Entity B.

We can get normal attributes of C like this.

```
A.findById(id,{include:[{model:B, through:{attributes:[...]}}]).
```

Obviously, we can not get target model D like the one above.

I tried

`A.findById(id,{include:[{model:B, through:{model:C, include:[model:D]}}])`

it didn't work.

---

Comment: Please add the schema for the model `C` and `D`. Or can we assume model C has attributes like `{ A_id, B_id, D_id, someother }`, A_id, B_id for through relation of A and B and D_id for belongsTo relation of D?

Comment: Yes. Actually, in my case, C has just {A_id, B_id, D_id}.

Comment: Will this `D.findAll({ include: [ model: C, where: { A_id: id } ] })`, solve your use case. Note: in this you can't include A or B. It will just provide all `terms of model D related to model A`, as you wrote.

Comment: In my case, D does not have a hasMany association to C. But once I add it, it does work.It solves my problem partly. Thank you. However, I expected to include A and B, too. Sorry I didn't describe it well. I think this is a common context for E-R design of database. D is an Entity, which is related to the Relation C of Entity A and Entity B.